# Visual Studio 13 code block with blue border

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

[image: Visual Studio 13 code block with blue border.]

why is this happening? Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed that may cause this?

Comment: No. I have not installed any.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly related to the Windows Narrator feature being turned on.
Try disabling it through the windows settings or if the shortcuts are enabled **Caps Lock + Esc**.